# Making a practice screen in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I want to make attached screen with provided CSS. How can I do it in an efficient way?[image: myimage]

```
table, td {
  border: solid black 2px;
}
.my-cashbook{
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
.action-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;

}
.input-amount{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 48px;
  left: 0;
}
.input-amount input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.action-group button {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.action-group .red{
  background: red;
}

.action-group .green{
  background: green;
}

.transaction{
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9c9c9c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #a2a2a2;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.transaction div{
  flex: 3;
}
.transaction .entry{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.transaction .entry h1{
  font-size: 1em;
}
.transaction .amount {

}
.transaction .in {
  color: green;
  background-color: #c1ffc1;
}
.transaction .out {
  background-color: #ffcbcb;
  color: red;
}
.cash-in-hand {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
}
.cash-in-hand h1{
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
}
.cash-in-hand p{
  color: gray;
}
.gray{
  color: gray;
}
.today-balance{
  position: fixed;
  top: 1%;
  right: 1%;
}
.today-balance h1{
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
}
.today-balance p{
  color: gray;
}
.model {
  background-color: #000000cc;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.model-content{
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.model-content input{
  width: 96%;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.model-content textarea{
  width: 98.6%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.model-content button{
  width: 100%;
}
.model-content button:disabled{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.model-content .green-btn{
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
.model-content .red-btn{
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.model-content .close-btn{
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #a9a9a9;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I know it is an easy for most of the developers but I an new to coding so need some reference to learn and explore. Please help.....................

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-fluid {
  background: #7F3300;
  padding: 35px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

.column-1 {
  background: #808080;
  padding: 35px;
}

.column-2 {
  background: #007F7F;
  padding: 35px;
}

.column-3 {
  background: #FF7F7F;
  padding: 35px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 column-1">

      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">

    </div>
     <div class="col-6 column-1">

      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">

    </div>
   <div class="col-6 column-1">

      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">

    </div>
     <div class="col-6 column-1">

      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use styles which are mentioned in css